# Adding collision detection from referencebounds view boundary to fix sliding issue

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am creating an app with a feature that has a random circle randomly bouncing around the screen. I was able to achieve this by using UIKitDynamics. The animator's reference view is set to `self.view` (the view for the screen). I added a UICollisionBehavior to the animator and set the UICollisionBehavior's `translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary` property to true so that the circle bounces around the screen.

Here's the issue: If the circle hits the boundary at a steep angle, it will eventually end up sliding up and down or left and right on one corner. **The only current solution is to set the magnitude property very high, but this ruins the look and isn't a good solution.** Upon investigation, I saw many stack overflow posts with the same issue stating that this is a problem within iOS's own physics engine and with how they deal with floating point values. The solutions said to supply the collision with a UICollisionBehaviorDelegate and to add a bounce back with a slightly offset angle and/or speed. I can't figure out how to implement the solution with UIKitDynamics.

My questions are:

1. How can I reference the reference view boundary in a UICollisionDelegate considering the collisionbehavior function takes in a boundary identifier, or 2 different UIDynamics items, and the translatereferenceboundsintoboundary isn't either of those. Adding a new boundary requires either 2 CGPoints or a UIBezierPath, so maybe create a UIBezierPath in the form of the screen? How would I do that?
2. After question one is solved, how would I go about offsetting the value so it never gets stuck going back and forth in a corner? The solutions given involve using an applyImpulse from SpriteKit, but I can't find a similar method in UIKitDynamics. Closest things are `addAngularVelocity` and `addLinearVelocity` under UIDynamicItemBehavior.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollisionBehaviorDelegate {
//    Reference for circles button in code, initilization of animator for circle movement
    @IBOutlet var selfie: UIButton!
    var animator: UIDynamicAnimator?

//    If the ball is touched trigger popup
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let touchLocation  = touch!.location(in: self.view)
        if self.selfie.layer.presentation()!.hitTest(touchLocation) != nil {
          performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMessageView", sender: self)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)
//        Initial push for circles
        let push = UIPushBehavior(items: [selfie], mode: .instantaneous)
        push.magnitude = 3
        push.angle = CGFloat.random(in: 0...2*CGFloat.pi)
        animator?.addBehavior(push)
//        Add collision boundary around edges of the screen
        let boundaries = UICollisionBehavior(items: [selfie])
        boundaries.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true
        boundaries.add
//        Add collision detection to circles, circles
        boundaries.collisionDelegate = self
        func collisionBehavior(_ behavior: UICollisionBehavior, endedContactFor item: UIDynamicItem, withBoundaryIdentifier identifier: NSCopying?) {
//            1. Figure out how to reference boundary for collision
//            2. Figure out how to add bounce back to slightly offsetted angle and speed
        }
        animator?.addBehavior(boundaries)
//        Properties for circles
        let circleProperties = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [selfie])
        circleProperties.elasticity = 1
        circleProperties.friction = 0
        circleProperties.resistance = 0
        circleProperties.density = 1
        circleProperties.allowsRotation = false
        animator?.addBehavior(circleProperties)
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI - you can't have the delegate methods inside `viewDidLoad` (or any other function).

Comment: Thanks for the help, sorry I am new to iOS programming and this is my first project. So I should just move the func collisionBehavior outside the viewDidLoad and just put it under?

Comment: It should be just another function inside the class.

Comment: @nahjb - are you saying that if your (random) `push.angle` happens to be, say, 45-degrees (.pi * 0.25), the collision will eventually start sliding along an edge? If you provide a link or two for *"solutions given involve using an applyImpulse from SpriteKit"* we might be able to offer a similar solution with UIKitDynamics

Comment: I found a kind of hacky solution that sort-of works. By suppling a function which detects contact and then does an action. The action I supplied was a slight magnitude change at a random angle. It's not perfect and there's definitely a better solution, but it works for now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this one out. Requires a bit of geometry understanding (unit circle). The approach to solve this was right. You do want to make a collisionbehaviordelegate function so that when a ball does end up sliding alongside a edge of the screen, a collision is detected and a small momentum will be given pushing the ball back off the edge. You use the point that the collision was detected at to set the UIDynamicItem to bounce back at a random direction that is the opposite of the collision. The balls will never end up hitting the outer view at a steep angle and won't slide back and forth. **Note this also includes changing the UIDynamicItems elasticity to less than 1, say 0.9** Here's the code:

```
   func collisionBehavior(_ behavior: UICollisionBehavior, beganContactFor item: UIDynamicItem, withBoundaryIdentifier identifier: NSCopying?, at p: CGPoint) {
    let threshold: CGFloat = 1
    var pushDirection: CGFloat = 0
    // Collision detected on left side, set angle to be somewhere opposite
    if p.x <= threshold {
        pushDirection = CGFloat.random(in: degreesToRadians(degrees: 300)...degreesToRadians(degrees: 420))
    // Collision detected on right side, set angle to be somewhere opposite
    } else if p.x >= view.bounds.width - threshold {
        pushDirection = CGFloat.random(in: degreesToRadians(degrees: 120)...degreesToRadians(degrees: 240))
    // Collision detected on top, set angle to be somewhere opposite
    } else if p.y <= threshold {
        pushDirection = CGFloat.random(in: degreesToRadians(degrees: 210)...degreesToRadians(degrees: 330))
    // Collision detected on bottom, set angle to be somewhere opposite
    } else if p.y >= view.bounds.height - threshold {
        pushDirection = CGFloat.random(in: degreesToRadians(degrees: 30)...degreesToRadians(degrees: 150))
    }
    if pushDirection != 0 {
        let movement = UIPushBehavior(items: [item], mode: .instantaneous)
        movement.magnitude = 0.4
        movement.angle = pushDirection
        animator?.addBehavior(movement)
    }
}
```